# Chrome extension fires multiple times on one page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to wrap my head around how these extensions work.  Right now I'm sending a message from content script to the background.  I tried both single messages and a long-lived connection.  For each page, the console registers multiple logs...and I have no idea why.  The scripts are simple:

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({hi: "hi"}, function(response) {});
//or
//var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "test"});
//port.postMessage({hi: "hi"});
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab);
    console.log(request.hi);
});
//OR
/*chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    });
});*/
```

manifest.json

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
},
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end",
    "all_frames": true
}],
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>"
]
```

In each case, like I said, I get three logs in the background page.  Why?  I thought it might be due to the number of tabs I have open but the logs show the sender information and it says it comes from the same tab.

MORE: When I refresh this question, I only get one log entry (one entry per block, as in the first comment).  When I refresh google results or the Google extensions API page, I get multiple logs.

Comment: 3 logs you mean 3*2 logs, since you console.log 2 times for each message? And by the way, maybe you disable all_frames and try it again.

Comment: @xwhyLikeThis yes, 3*2.

Comment: @xwhyLikeThis dammit seriously??? It was that simple?  In laymen's terms, can you explain to me what that did, what top frame and all frames means?

Comment: I am happy it works. all_frames means your content scripts will be inject to all the frames in the page, i.e. the document and all the documents inside the iframe node. I think your page may have two iframe node, so the content script is been injected 3 times...But I just guess it before you have tested it. And it depends on what you want to do for the content script, maybe all_frames is required if you want to control all the elements in the page.

Comment: @xwhyLikeThis Yeah, that's what I was wondering. So if I were looking through the DOM for something, if that something was inside another frame, would I not be able to find it?  Or am I not understanding what the iframe node is?

Comment: your javascript can only find DOM in the document that your script in. It can't find DOM in child iframe or sibling iframe, I think this is because of the cross-origin policy or other security related things. So if your content script wants to find all the DOM nodes of some type(for example the ads...), you need to set all_frames true and  so that chrome will inject your script to all the documents.

Comment: @xwhyLikeThis Thanks, I understand now.  I have a more in-depth question on a different topic, can we move this into chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80382/discussion-between-denikov-and-xwhylikethis).

Comment: not sure why none of you guys have actually written an answer. o wanted to answer but it's already in the comments so move it to an answer.